# Group permission on files created by sudoing as a different user

Tags: unix, file-permissions, sudo

I am creating some files by sudoing as a user u1.

sudo -u u1 touch file1.txt. The files are created with g-w permission. When I login as u1 and create a file, the file gets created with g+s permission.

How can I create the files with g+s permission using sudo -u command ?
The umask value for u1 is 002.

Thanks

Comment: the umask is being set by one of the login scripts, you need to invoke the login scripts to ensure that the variable is set. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create the files with g+s permission using sudo -u command ?

```
sudo -u u1 sh -c 'touch file1.txt && chmod g+s file1.txt'
```